# How to jump to a specified function name using help() command

Tags: python, console, helper

I always use `help(object)` command in Python and I would like to know is there any way I can skip most of the text and kind of jump to the function that I want. For example:

```
>>> import boto
>>> s3 = boto.connect_s3()
>>> help(s3)
```

It gives me a very long description of this object:

```
Help on S3Connection in module boto.s3.connection object:
...
...
...
server_name(self, port=None)
```

To be more clear, can I do something like:

```
>>> help(s3, server_name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass in the method:

```
help(s3.server_name)
```

Comment: What about `dir` command, is it possible to list functions that matches some regex? for example if I want to list all functions, that starts with `set_` is there any way to do it similar to `dir(s3.set_*)`

Comment: @Vor: I'd use a list comprehension: `[f for f in dir(s3) if f.startswith('set_')]`